# MLE for Naive Bayes in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, e1071, naive-bayes

I am using the `naivebayes` function of the [e1071](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/index.html) library. Some example commands are:

```
model = naiveBayes(Species ~ ., data = iris)
pred = predict(model, iris[,])
```

My question is: how can I obtain the maximum likelihood estimate for the conditional probability distribution of this model?

Comment: Crossposting between here and StackOverflow is discouraged.

Comment: I would suggest that this would be the more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: sorry for crossposting.i didn't know here when i posted the question to stackoverflow.somebody suggested here and i posted here then. thanks.

Comment: At the very least, you should provide the link to the other posting.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit ambiguous... What's wrong with `model$table`?

Comment: unfortunately, i have no background in statistics so i don't know what to expect from a "MLE" output. sorry for that. so, when i print model$table, i get something like below. is this MLE?                                                          
            Sepal.Length                                               
Y             [,1]      [,2]                                           
  setosa     5.006 0.3524897                                           
  versicolor 5.936 0.5161711                                           
  virginica  6.588 0.6358796

Comment: @Yuan I don't know, because simple "MLE" can mean different things... Try reading ?naivebayes, it is quite detail description what is what in table, maybe you could find something familiar there. Or try to specify what you need in more detailed way -- what is your desired use, for what you need it?